# Lie derivative of a volume form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-fields

Let $M$ be a $3-$dimensional orientable manifold. Suppose $\Omega = dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ a volume form on it.

How can I compute explicitly the Lie derivative of it along the vector field
$$ X = x\partial_x + y\partial_y+ xy\partial_{z}? $$

I see that by Cartan's formula we get $\mathcal{L}_X\Omega = di_X\Omega$, but how can I compute explicitly the contraction on the right?

By definition I think I should take 3 test vector fields $Y_1,Y_2$ so that I get
$$ (i_X\Omega)(Y_1,Y_2)=\Omega(X,Y_1,Y_2), $$
but how can I compute this simply?

Comment: Use the derivation rule $$i_{X}(\alpha\wedge\beta)=(i_{X}\alpha)\wedge\beta + (-1)^{p}\alpha\wedge(i_{X}\beta)$$ for $\alpha\in\Omega^{p}(M)$ and $\beta\in\Omega^{k}(M)$.

Comment: Oh ok, so I should consider like $\beta=dy\wedge dz$ and hence $\Omega=dx\wedge \beta$ so the classical approach holds. Did I understand correctly @studiosus ?

Comment: Yes, using twice the derivation rule, you get $$i_{X}(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)=(i_{X}dx) dy\wedge dz -(i_{X}dy)dx\wedge dz+(i_{X}dz)dx\wedge dy.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$1).\ $ We have the Leibnitz rule

$L_X\Omega=L_Xdx\wedge dy\wedge dz+dx\wedge L_Xdy\wedge dz+dx\wedge dy\wedge L_Xdz$

$2).\ $ $L_X$ commutes with the exterior derivative; that is, $L_Xd\omega=dL_X\omega$ for any $k$-form, $\omega$

$3).\ $ The Lie derivative of a $C^\infty$ function $f$ is $L_Xf=Xf$

Answer (score 0):

For $X=x\,\partial_x+y\,\partial_y+xy\,\partial_z$ and $\Omega=dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$
we get, using
$$
dx(X)=x\,,\quad dy(X)=y\,,\quad dz(X)=xy\,,
$$
that the contraction is
$$
i_X\Omega=x\,dy\wedge dz-y\,dx\wedge dz+xy\,dx\wedge dy\,.
$$
In this case,
$$
d\,(i_X\Omega)=dx\wedge dy\wedge dz-dy\wedge dx\wedge dz+0=2\,\Omega\,.
$$
The Lie derivative of $\Omega$ w.r.t. $X$ is therefore by, [Cartan's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_formula),
$$
L_X\Omega=d\,(i_X\Omega)+i_X\,\underbrace{d\Omega}_{0}=2\,\Omega\,.
$$
Neat!